# How to increment a table column using postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I would like to add some new values to `ic_countries` (plunet_english column), but I would also like to increment the id (`landid`).  The table is set to unique id, but not auto increment.

Sadly my approach below provides an error around `lastval()+1` as undefined.  I have tried to add a function that increments starting from a hard coded value. Even that seems unobtainable.

```
INSERT INTO ic_countries (landid, plunet_english)
SELECT lastval()+1, name
FROM country
WHERE name NOT IN 
    (
    SELECT plunet_english
    FROM ic_countries
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the auto-increment in an existing table then do this

get the next number for field `landid` by using
`SELECT MAX(landid) + 1 FROM ic_countries` if its `100` then

create a sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_ic_countries_landid START WITH 100;
```

assign this sequence for the table

```
ALTER TABLE ic_countries ALTER COLUMN landid SET DEFAULT nextval('seq_ic_countries_landid');
```

now you can insert like below :

```
INSERT INTO ic_countries ( plunet_english)
SELECT  name --landid will be automatically increment
FROM country
WHERE name NOT IN 
    (
    SELECT plunet_english
    FROM ic_countries
    )
```

Comment: max(landid)+1 fails when you have concurrent queries do the same thing: They all return the same result.

Comment: Good answer, +1!  @FrankHeikens: your comment seems entirely out of place for the question, it doesn't look like a very concurrent environment at all.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: the max() is only used to initialize the sequence properly.

Comment: This will work great.  I am using this table as a simulated spreadsheet so my logic did not go far enough to treat the table in its natural postgresql environment. Thanks